# .htaccess RewriteRule / Redirect based on query string/parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I rewrite in .htaccess a call to this URL:

```
www.domain.com/?_wpm_gateway=paypal-standard&_wpm_action=ipn
```

To point to a new IPN URL (for Paypal payments):

```
www.domain.com/payments/paypal/ipn
```

With, obviously, the rest of the parameters in the IPN itself being passed on and sent over to the new URL?

Any idea?

And I need a rewrite rule ONLY if that query/URL is called, as otherwise it should be business as normal, so to speak.

EDIT: I tried this, but didn't work... ideas?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)_wpm_action=ipn(?:$|&)
RewriteRule ^ /payments/paypal/ipn? [NS,L,DPI,QSD]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it back to front. You tell PayPal what your new IPN URL is either in your merchant settings, or per transaction in the payment parameters you send. You don't redirect the incoming IPN from PayPal. If you were worried about missed IPNs, you would do a silent internal rewrite of the old to new so it can be processed *without* redirection.

---

**Edit:** example of internal rewrite from old url to new. **Edit again** it should hit the later rule on the next pass, but you can make it happen quicker in that `.htaccess`

```
# ensure only rewrite old paypal when query has exactly right parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)_wpm_action=ipn(?:$|&)
# should only happen on first request and allow the pretty url to be routed normally on the next pass through the rules
RewriteRule ^ payments/paypal/ipn [NS,DPI,QSD]
```

Comment: Well, I did set the new IPN in Paypal, but that doesn't apply for existing/previous recurring transactions as they still go to the old IPN (if there was a way to update it for all the old transactions too, I would've already done that). And yes, that is why I need this redirect made, as the old IPNs are going to that URL specified and I need them redirected to the new URL.

Comment: Hmm, that's still not pushing any of those IPN notifications over to the specified URL for some reason, even though it looks good on paper to me as well.

Comment: Sure. See above. Just a standard Wordpress .htaccess (out of the box one).

Comment: Back to front again. Put the custom section first, otherwise WordPress gets it before your rule is ever processed. And the edit you posted doesn't contain the correct condition.

Comment: Hmm, updated the htaccess file as per your suggestions, and updated the original question with what's in place right now, and it still doesn't work / pass the IPN query over to that new URL.

Comment: Updated answer. You don't need `?` in the substituted URL with the `QSD` flag, and don't add the leading `/`. You should test the code before accepting the answer.

Comment: Also, make sure you're substituting the canonical URL, you don't want any redirects happening. E.g. if it expects a trailing slash, use one.